# Where can I find the source code for `native` methods in Java library?

Tags: java-8, native, atomic, java

In the `sun.misc` package, I saw these methods under `Unsafe` class.

```
public final native boolean compareAndSwapObject(Object var1, long var2, Object var4, Object var5);

public final native boolean compareAndSwapInt(Object var1, long var2, int var4, int var5);

public final native boolean compareAndSwapLong(Object var1, long var2, long var4, long var6);
```

It seems that these methods are atomic and are written in C, but I can't find the source code for these method on Github.. Does anyone have any ideas about this? How can I find an open-source implementation for these methods easily?

Answer (score 8):

You can check out the OpenJDK code here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/unsafe.cpp

Comment: The problem is, for a given native method, how to find the source code location in JDK?

Answer (score 1):

You can download OpenJdk source code [JDK7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7). There is a folder share(jdk\src\share) where you can get source code. The folder native (jdk\src\share\native) has source written (in c and c++):

1. jdk\src\linux source for linux.
2. jdk\src\windows source for windows.
3. jdk\src\solaris souce for solaris.
4. jd\src\share common source.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Buddy

Finally I find source code in the Github mirror for jdk7-hotspot here:

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/prims/unsafe.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Your question specifically asks for `java 8`. Run this from command line (you need `Mercurial` client installed)

```
hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8
```

This will get you source code for `HotSpot` and everything else.